# place a question mark immediately beside a spinner at the far right-end android

Tags: android, xml

I want to place an image at the far right of a spinner in my android view. On attaching the image it jumps below the spinner. This is the code snippet of the attempt

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerm"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="53dp" />
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/qmark"
                    android:src="@drawable/qmark"
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="openFile" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

my challenge is to place the question mark at the far right-end of the spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/qmark"
        android:layout_height="53dp" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/qmark"
        android:src="@drawable/qmark"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:onClick="openFile"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LinearLayout` for this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerm"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="53dp" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/qmark"
        android:src="@drawable/qmark"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="openFile" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerm"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/qmark"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="53dp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/qmark"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="openFile" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```